# Updating iOS Widget every time it appears

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget

I am building out a widget in SwiftUI and understand the timeline, but is there a way to update the timeline every time the widget appears on the users device? I want to make a call to an API so that the data is up to date without calling on it every couple minutes. Is this possible?

Comment: My suspicion is that the closest you're going to get is providing a timeline with many entires, all as close together as possible.

Comment: That's what I have right now, but It uses too many API calls.

Comment: I don't know how or what your API returns, but I'm not suggesting to call the API each time. I'm suggesting to call the API a limited number of times and provide a timeline to the iOS widget system with many entries.

Comment: That would be ideal but it is for live sports scores, so it needs to be updated every couple minutes

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a widget that will update constantly because the OS will throttle it.

The best you can do for a live sports score widget like you describe is specify a future date at a given interval (for example, 5 minutes, which may still be too aggressive) for the `policy` property of your `Timeline` entry using `.after(Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 5)`.

You'd also want to be smart with your widget and only specify that short of an interval during a known match/game time.

I'd highly recommend taking a close read through the `Determining a Refresh Policy` and `Refreshing Widgets Efficiently` section of Apple's [Time Provider Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/timelineprovider#see-also). If you abuse the refresh interval, the OS will throttle how quickly your app is allowed to refresh.